# For Chrome extension publishing purposes, does using a Bootstrap CDN count as remote code?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, remote-access, cdn

I am trying to publish a Google Chrome Extension. Before doing it, there is a form to fill:

[image]

I am unsure about how to answer. The extension does use a bootstrap CDN via:

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

On the side it says:

> Remote code is any JS, Wasm, or CSS that is not included in the extension's package. This includes references to external files in  tags, modules pointing to external files, and strings evaluated through eval()

Is this CDN use considered as remote code? Is it considered a module pointing to an external file?

Comment: I would say it's considered a reference to an external file in tag.

Comment: CSS is not executable code so the built-in ManifestV3 restriction doesn't apply, although it's bad practice anyway as it makes your extension unusable offline or in case of a network problem, which is why Chrome Web Store discourages remote CSS as well as executable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, remote code would include CSS files served by a CDN. There are various areas in the Chrome Extensions documentation that specifically define remote code as any code not bundled in your extension. They even include "Any library hosted on a CDN". In fact, they actually specifically reference Bootstrap on the [Remotely hosted code restrictions page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code).

Although CSS is not something blocked by the new Manifest V3 restrictions on remote code, including remote code can make the review process take longer. Instead, it's better to include the library bundled with the extension (assuming the library's license allows it).